# Magento 2 (CE) not displaying the Checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-community, magento-2.0.2

I tried to run Magento(CE) 2.1.0 in my localhost but it seems that **my checkout page isn't displaying anything, just header and footer.**

I am new to magentoif anyone could help that would be great.

This is my checkout page:
[image: This is the screenshot]

Comment: Have you run deploy command

Comment: you can try this: hope this will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123401/39739

Comment: yes. but still not working.

Comment: what is your OS (ubuntu or centOS,...)?

Comment: it's windows 8.1. I run the Magento on the WAMP

Comment: Here is solution for this [click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128434/33772)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using wamp server on windows localhost then,

you can try this:

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

in your CLI.

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to first remove all files and folder from `pub/static` folder content.

Remove **`var`** folder.

Run command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clear Browser cache.

Try again.

Answer (score 0):

In vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Format.php comment out line 112 and add

```
//$defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?:       self::$defaultNumberSet;
  $defaultSet = self::$defaultNumberSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel side

> system -> cache management -> Flush Cache Storage.

[image]

after that change the permission to www-data or root

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magentoApplication/