# Magento 2.1.0 Checkout page is blank

Tags: checkout, error, magento-2.1

After upgrading to 2.1.0 my checkout page looks like this
[image]

In console there is an error

```
 TypeError: window.checkout is undefined
```

[image]

I tryed what was suggested here [Magento 2 (CE) not displaying the Checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123532/magento-2-ce-not-displaying-the-checkout-page) but it did not help

Comment: flush cache , then change to developer mode and check

Comment: unfortunately, did not work

Comment: now it shows error Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Magento\Framework\Locale\Format::getPriceFormat(): Cannot load resource element 'default' in \vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Format.php on line 112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solution works for me:

In vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Format.php comment out line 112 and add

```
//$defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?:     self::$defaultNumberSet;
  $defaultSet = self::$defaultNumberSet;
```

Comment: Awesome! worked for me. How did you find this out? Just curious